# Lower log level for Quartz

Tags: quartz.net, serilog, graylog

I am using Serilog in my .NETCore servers with several sinks such as console, file and graylog (GELF) for my cloud deployments.

As soon as I set the log-level to DEBUG I get messages from the quartz scheduler thread every few seconds. How can I turn this OFF? It shows thousands of useless entries like so:

`2018-11-27 22:09:35.210 +00:00 [DBG] [Quartz.Core.QuartzSchedulerThread] [ThreadId 5] Batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2018-11-27 22:10:04.038 +00:00 [DBG] [Quartz.Core.QuartzSchedulerThread] [ThreadId 5] Batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2018-11-27 22:10:30.869 +00:00 [DBG] [Quartz.Core.QuartzSchedulerThread] [ThreadId 5] Batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2018-11-27 22:11:00.591 +00:00 [DBG] [Quartz.Core.QuartzSchedulerThread] [ThreadId 5] Batch acquisition of 0 triggers`

I wrote a REST API to dynamically change the log level without restarting the services (see `_logLevelSwitch` in the config below). However, I do **NOT want external libraries to inherit the log level for my code**. How can this be done?

I managed to do this for the `source` Microsoft using `.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)` in my Serilog configuration. But `Quartz` is a library and its source is the name of my own binary, so I cannot lower the loglevel in the same way. Here is my Serilog configuration (the general part, other props are set depending on the runtime environment)

```
        var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(_logLevelSwitch)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .Enrich.WithProcessName()
            .Enrich.WithThreadId()
            .Enrich.WithMachineName()
            .Enrich.WithAssemblyName();
```

And then I use additional runtime specific configuration code like:

```
switch (po.Runtime)
{
    case Runtime.DevelLocal:
        loggerConfig.Enrich.WithProperty(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("runtime", CommonConstants.RtDevelLocal));
        _logLevelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Debug;
        loggerConfig.WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] [{SourceContext}] " +
                                                     "[ThreadId {ThreadId}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}");
        loggerConfig.WriteTo.File(Path.Combine(po.LogPath, $"{BbDeConstants.ProductName}-.log"), rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
            outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] [{SourceContext}] " +
                            "[ThreadId {ThreadId}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}");
        break;
    case Runtime.DemoDatacenter:
        loggerConfig.Enrich.WithProperty(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("runtime", CommonConstants.RtDemoDatacenter));
        loggerConfig.WriteTo.Graylog(new GraylogSinkOptions
        {
            HostnameOrAddress = po.LogHost,
            TransportType = TransportType.Udp,
            Port = 12201,
            Facility = "BizBus",
        });
        break;
    .....
}
```

I read that `Quartz.Net` is using `Commons.logging` but I do not use it and I have **no configuration for it**.

Any idea how to get rid of those `Quartz.Core.QuartzSchedulerThread` messages?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by adding this line to my Serilog config:

```
   .MinimumLevel.Override("Quartz", LogEventLevel.Information)
```

So your config would be:

```
     var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(_logLevelSwitch)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Quartz", LogEventLevel.Information)
        .Enrich.WithProcessName()
        .Enrich.WithThreadId()
        .Enrich.WithMachineName()
        .Enrich.WithAssemblyName();
```

Comment: Thank you my log files are free again!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in .NET Core:

**appsettings.json:**

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Quartz": "Information",
      "Quartz.Core.QuartzSchedulerThread": "Information",
      "Quartz.Core.JobRunShell": "Information"
    }
  },
```